# Javascript saying a key does not exist in an object even though it does

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am creating an admin panel.
For some reason, my code returns an error saying banned users does not exist even though it is in the Object. This confuses me alot and I dont know how to solve it. I got the error originally that says `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`, and when I logged the key banned_users, it returns undefined. I even tried logging the data in the console after it, but it still has the key banned_users in it.

Here is my code that handles the response:

```
fetch('/admin_info')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      data.admins.forEach((admin) => {
        var list_admin = document.createElement('li');
        if (admin != data.owner && admin != data.admin_username) {
          list_admin.className = 'list_admin';
          list_admin.onclick = function (){
            remove_admin(admin)
          }
        }
        list_admin.id = `admin_${admin}`;
        if (admin == data.owner){
          list_admin.innerText = `${admin} (Owner)`
        }else{
          list_admin.innerText = admin
        }
        admin_list.appendChild(list_admin);
      });
    })
      //Problem Code
      banned_users = data.banned_users
      console.log(data.banned_users)
      banned_users.forEach((user) => {
      var banned_user = document.createElement('li');
      banned_user.className = 'banned_user';
      banned_user.innerText = user
      banned_user.appendChild(banned_list)
    //
    })
    .catch(error => {
      error_display.style.display = 'block';
      error_text.innerText = `Admin Panel failed to load: ${error}`;
    });
}
```

This is the JSON it is receiving as a response:

```
"admin_username":"Username",
"admins":["Username1","Username2"],
"banned_users":{"test":{}},"owner":"Username"}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?
Edit: I am also having an issue with saying data.banned_users or data["banned_users"] since it's not getting the key from the JSON and returning undefined for some reason

Comment: `banned_users` is an Object. Objects don't have a `forEach` method, that would be Arrays

Comment: Use a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead of `forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `banned_users` is an Object. Objects don't have a `forEach` method, only Arrays do. Instead of `forEach`, use a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```
  for (let user in banned_users) {
    var banned_user = document.createElement('li');
      banned_user.className = 'banned_user';
      banned_user.innerText = user
      banned_user.appendChild(banned_list)
}
```

Does this code work? I don't see `banned_list` referred to anywhere else. But the structure stands...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still returns undefined if I just say "data.banned_users" in general

Comment: You need to move this code block inside the block that opens with `.then(data => {`, ie, move everything from the `//Problem Code` comment to the `appendChild` two lines up.

Answer (score 1):

In your response, `banned_users` is an Object. Objects do not have a `forEach` method. Instead, you can try something like this:

```
for (var user in banned_users) {
    var banned_user = document.createElement('li');
    banned_user.className = 'banned_user';
    banned_user.innerText = user
    banned_user.appendChild(banned_list)
}
```